# Schedule tasks to remove table entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

Can someone assist me setting up a cron job using the whenever gem? I want to clear the Notifications, Conversations, and Receipts tables every 90 days from the created_at dates.

I'm not sure how to fill it in.

`every 90.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting from a bad side. You should run task *every day*. The task will delete all Notification, Conversations and Receipts older than 90 days.

```
class Notification

   scope :old, -> { where(["created_at < ?", 90.days.ago]) }

end

# schedule.rb
every 1.day do
  runner "Notification.old.destroy"
end
```

Something like that.

Comment: That makes sense. Should I place the `scope :old, -> { where(["created_at < ?", 90.days.ago]) }` is a rake file? I have cron jobs setup for this already, I just found the whenever gem as I wanted something that could do it automatically so I don't have to continue manually entering in three different commands such as `rake remove_old_notifications`, etc. This is for the mailboxer gem fyi.

Comment: Add this scope to each of class Notification, Conversation and Receipt.

Comment: is Capistrano required for this to work, and how can you test to see the results locally or does this only work in production